# How do I remap the buttons on an Apple Mighty Mouse?

Tags: mouse

I just started using Ubuntu instead of Windows, my initial reaction was "omg this is awful", but after a while it grew on me, and I don't plan on going back to Windows. However I have an [Apple Mighty Mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Mighty_Mouse) which I was given today, and the buttons on it don't quite work.

Left and right click work, so does scrolling right and down, also the back button works. However the forward button goes back, and the scroll up button sometimes scrolls down, scrolling left just doesn't work.

Is there a way to fix this? Like remap the buttons? I'm not entirely sure how the driver thing works in Ubuntu?

Comment: Is this the "Apple Magic Mouse"? Could you provide a link to the device? Us being Ubuntu/Linux users we know little about such crazy things :)

Comment: @Marco Ceppi, it's a different mouse. I think he's talking about this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Mighty_Mouse

Comment: Yes I mean what WarriorIng64 linked to.

Comment: What I would do is get a regular PC mouse that supports USB... and use that... yes it will work... I know you Mac People thrive off your one button, but Ubuntu is designed for 2+ mouse buttons and you will find it a lot easier to use, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

The side buttons are just one physical button, meant to be squeezed from both sides.  It does indeed show up as button 8.

Answer (score 1):

If I was in your place, I'd probably buy another mouse (costs something like $10).

However if you insist, you might try to map the keys manually.

You can use xev to find the keycodes. Open a terminal, type `xev` and press enter and a small window will appear. Put the cursor there and do the special keystrokes. You will find the keycodes in the terminal. Then use these codes in the keymapper of your Ubuntu.

BTW, what Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: I have the latest Ubuntu (I'm pretty sure) 11.04, what do you mean by keymapper?

Comment: Using XEV, I get the forward and backward buttons both returning button 8?? Is a GUI to change the mouse buttons.

Comment: mmm there seems to be the issue. You would expect to get button 1 (left), button 2 (scroll-wheel) and button 3 (right)

Keymapper is the utility that can re-assign keys or shortcuts (sometimes this is a file to edit, but Gnome and KDE use a GUI software to do this). From what you have said, I believe that you have the Unity desktop. I don't have this, so refer to its documentation or add the tag "unity" to your question to attract specialists on that. However most probably you would have something in the menu's or icons such as system, control panel, keyboard, ...

Comment: Btw (1) if both buttons of the mouse give button 8 with xev, then I would tend to believe that the thing is faulty

Comment: Btw (2) It might be that unity allows you to map a key to an action without knowing the keycode (in that case--sorry--the info from xev is not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

This is a persistent Kernel bug reported since Ubuntu 7:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/319053

There seems to be some versions of Kernel that work well with the Apple Mighty Mouse while others do not.

For me the Ubuntu 13.04 Kernel: vmlinuz-3.8.0-31-generic supported the Mighty Mouse with proper button functions while;
Ubuntu 13.10 Kernel: vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic did not. This bug is still seen in 13.10

Answer (score 0):

A couple choices:

The package `piper` is a GUI for working with `ratbagd`, which allows for more advanced mapping of mouse buttons and functions. Ubuntu 20.04 includes it in the [focal, inside universe repository](https://github.com/libratbag/piper/wiki/Installation). Debian includes it in Bullseye and later.

Or, more simply for a device like the Mighty Mouse, use `xmodmap.` Enter `xmodmap -pp` to get a current map of the mouse buttons. Button 1 is left click; 2 is middle; 3 is right click; 4 and 5 are up/down scrolling; and so on. Type `xmodmap -help` or `man xmodmap` for more info. When you've got your new button mapping figured out, run `xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"`, but rearrange the numbers to match your new mapping.

For example, if your Mighty Mouse has twitchy squeeze buttons and you want to disable them, you might enter `xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 8 9"` and remap button 8 (fourth button) function to button 10, which usually doesn't have a default function. This works in Gnome 3.30, Debian Buster. It should work in Ubuntu as well.